# Symbolic link starting with .#

Tags: files, emacs, filenames, symlink

I have a symlink in one of my directories that has the following name:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 XXXX ZZZ   37 Jan 15 18:18 .#perl.org -> XXX@YYY.com.2980:1344441539
```

I am wondering what this symlink represents and which program/action created it.

By the way, I have a file in this directory called `perl.org` that I have been working on for the last few days. I connect with `ssh -Y` and then run `emacs` to edit this and other files.

Comment: This one starts with `.` and not with a `#`.

Comment: In most unix/linux filesystems, any character except `/` and NUL is allowed in a filename/dirname. Someone made up that name.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs creates these files as "lock files".

From Emacs help section "22.3.4 Protection against Simultaneous Editing"

> When you make the first modification in an Emacs buffer that is
>   visiting a file, Emacs records that the file is "locked" by you.  (It
>   does this by creating a specially-named symbolic link in the same
>   directory.)  Emacs removes the lock when you save the changes.  The
>   idea is that the file is locked whenever an Emacs buffer visiting it
>   has unsaved changes.

In that section it does not say how the files are named, but I have seen files created by Emacs with the exact pattern of your file. I.e. a symlink named `.#(original filename)` that is a symlink to `user@host.emacsPID:timestamp`.

So, in your case [`.#perl.org` -> `XXX@YYY.com.2980:1344441539`] the file `perl.org` has been edited (and not saved) by user `XXX` at host `YYY.com` using an emacs session with PID `2980` at time `1344441539`=Wed Aug  8 17:58:59 CEST 2012.

Hint: use `date -d@1344441539` to convert the timestamp to human-readable form.